# Was this answer really no "review audit" question?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audit, specific-answer

When I first saw this one 
https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/208658

I thought it was an audit review, lets flag it.

But then it didn't say a I passed or something like that.

Was somebody really seriously trying to give this as answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Apparently.

Note that the user is unregistered, and that the post itself is from a year and a half ago.

[Maybe it's time you learn about the true nature of the internet.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=trolling)